# „Wir gehen von einer Klärung der Angelegenheit aus“ – Was bedeutet das?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Am Ende einer Nachricht, die auf eine Anfrage antwortet, stand dieser Satz:

> Wir gehen von einer Klärung der Angelegenheit aus.

Was ist hier gemeint? Dass der Absender glaubt, er hat alles völlig geklärt?

Comment: Servus und willkommen beim Stackexchange der deutschen Sprache. Da du die [tour] schon besucht hast, bleibt mir nur noch, dich auf das [help] zu verweisen, falls du Fragen hast, wie die Seite funktioniert.

Comment: Etwas mehr Kontext wäre hier hilfreich, denke ich. Je nach dem sonstigen Inhalt des Schreibens könnte der Satz eventuell klarer sein. 
Ich vermute mal, dass das Schreiben irgend einen Mißstand zum Inhalt hat. Dann würde dieser Satz bedeuten, dass der Absender vom Adressaten erwartet, dass dieser die Angelegenheit bereinigt.

Comment: ...eine bei Klempnern und Wasserversorgern weit verbreitete Grußformel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Der Satz ist nicht eindeutig. Er kann meinen, dass der Absender davon ausgeht, dass die Sache mit der obenstehenden Antwort geklärt ist, er kann aber auch nur meinen, dass der Absender der Meinung ist, dass es eine einvernehmliche Lösung für das Problem geben wird. Im zweiten Fall würde im Text wahrscheinlich eine Aufforderung zu einer weitergehenden Diskussion oder für eine Terminvereinbarung stehen.

Comment: »My thoughts exactly« – warum lässt sich das so schlecht übersetzen? ;)

Comment: Ich hab den Satz spontan als "Wir gehen davon aus, dass die Angelegenheit geklärt wird" verstanden. Erst als ich OP's Frage "glaubt der Absender, er hat alles völlig geklärt" gelesen hatte, wurde mir bewusst, dass der Satz nicht eindeutig ist.

Answer (score 3):

Meiner Meinung nach könnte der Satz auch bedeuten, dass der Sender der Nachricht erwartet, dass das Problem durch den Empfänger gelöst wird.

Comment: Servus und willkommen beim Stackexchange der deutschen Sprache. Du kannst eine [tour] der Seite nehmen. Wenn du mehr darüber erfahren möchtest, wie sie funktioniert, besuche das [help].

Comment: Good catch. Das ist sogar sehr wahrscheinlich, und zeigt umso mehr auf, dass Kontext hier notwendig ist.